# Is the CEO's job now to prepare Stack Exchange for acquisition?

Tags: discussion, community

It's normal for a company to have a spate of firings 2-3 months after a new CEO is installed as they determine what cultural changes they want to make to an organization they must lead.  Bringing the company into alignment with the leader's goals is critical to the success of that leader's (and by proxy, the investor's) vision.  Probably the recent notable firing are merely the tip of the iceberg as this process proceeds.

Recent activity suggests this is happening as normal, but there are a few things missing - for instance announcing replacements for those positions.

While a few posts suggest they are after "growth" the actions seem to be out of step with long term growth, but appear intended to immediately increase the value of Stack Exchange.

Are the investors asking the company to position itself for acquisition? Do we have access to board meeting notes?

Comment: If it is, they won't say, and if it isn't, they won't say either. Yet another interesting question that will never be appropriately answered, I'm afraid.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi despite I fear you're likely right, it feels like we deserve an answer, those old and new, who come here all the time and those (like myself) who come now and then for help. The community far and wide deserves and has the right to know, especially since we've put the time, effort and love in

Comment: @SomeRandomPerson, I agree the community deserves to know that information, but the people who can answer do not read Meta in the first place, and apparently could not care less about what the community deserves or not. Sad state of affairs, but so goes life...

Comment: "Do we have access to board meeting notes?" If someone here had, that would be one of the most extra-ordinary things to have happen.

Comment: The closest to board meetings notes you'll likely get is [this video interview with Joel](https://youtu.be/zMfxd9y0cMY) where he goes into the plans for an IPO. You can also read a [summary of it by George Stocker on Twitter](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1218161698105892864).